# Is it possible to make shared database in ios?

Tags: ios, sharing

I am very beginner in IOS

I have several IOS applications. They log their actions via CouchDB. Now each application has its own log file.

Please help me to discover how to make all the applications to log in shared log file?

Sorry for my English

Comment: This is not possible, every app runs in their own sandbox and can't access files from other apps.

Comment: What about applications in app groups? It seems t]hat they are allowed to use one shared file. But here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) they are mentioned only for application extensions and I need to use them only with apps

Comment: As state you can share files with an extension but not with other app in the app groups. Only keychain acces is possible with app groups, but this would not be the correct place to store your log file.